# How can I embed subtitles into videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: command-line, video, conversion, ffmpeg, video-subtitles

I'm told it's possible to embed subtitles (`.srt`) into video files (`.avi`) using `ffmpeg`, but I can't find any mention of it in the man page. Is this possible? What command do I use?

Comment: A solution that worked for me with ffmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man ffmpeg`:

> Subtitle options:
>
> -scodec codec
>       Force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream).
>
> -newsubtitle
>       Add a new subtitle stream to the current output stream.
>
> -slang code
>       Set the ISO 639 language code (3 letters) of the current subtitle stream.

So: 
`ffmpeg -newsubtitle subtitles.srv -i video.avi ...`

Comment: If I use instead of `...` `result.avi` this command does not work `At least one output file must be specified`

Comment: Of course, `...` means "and whatever other options you need".

Comment: Sufficient is `ffmpeg -newsubtitle subtitles.srt -i video.avi result.avi` but this ends with the message above. I hoped that result.avi is output file. I tried it with `-o result.avi` too but without success.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work for me (maybe wrong file or problem with ffmpeg). I tried this command instead `mencoder movie.avi -sub movie.srt -o movie.hardsubs.avi -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavcopts vbitrate=1200`

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff: This did not work for me either. What version of ffmpeg are you using, and what OS?

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, check whether your `ffmpeg` is from `libav-tools` or similar, or actually from the ffmpeg project, since there has been a fork.

Answer (score 4):

From Pier's link, specifically:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi
```

This creates a hard-sub ("burns" the subtitles into the video images) so you can't hide the subtitles and the change is irreversible!

I've used this successfully with the current static git ffmpeg release.

Comment: Doesn't work. "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Comment: This filter requires ffmpeg to be compiled with --enable-libass, [according documentation.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo)

Comment: Thx, resulting subtitles was smaller than i am used to, i would increase 50%. Someone mention: `subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='Fontsize=20'` https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` developers are working with subtitle support, but as far as I know it's only working in the latest ffmpeg. `mencoder` will burn subtitles instantly, if you want to try that instead.