# How can I embed Subtitles into an MP4 Generated with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, c#

**This isnt a duplicate of [How can I embed subtitles into videos with ffmpeg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/how-can-i-embed-subtitles-into-videos-with-ffmpeg)
Im asking for something else, and that question didnt solve my problem.**

So im making a string Concatenation XAML App that downloads the video and converts it with ffmpeg to mp4.

I want to merge the .ass or .srt (Subtitle file lol) with the .mp4 within my app, how can I do this automatically with FFMpeg?

also, I cant select the file names based on their names, it needs to be automatic, so is there a way i can ***"detect for files with the same names, 1 with mp4, and 1 with .ass/.srt and then merge the subtitle file with the mp4"***?

The reason I ask that is because the subtitle file and mp4 have the same names:
EX:

Show Name Episode 1 Season 1 - Episode Title.enUS.ass

Show Name Episode 1 Season 1 - Episode Title.mp4

Comment: Please explain why [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/how-can-i-embed-subtitles-into-videos-with-ffmpeg] didn't help you or how it failed

Comment: @mattia.b89 I dont know how to adapt it into C# as I dont know how to activate and write to the command line proccess

Comment: I think this question should be moved to programming stackexchange...